# My custom page template with is_user_logged_in() does not detect that I'm logged in

Tags: users, login, authentication, private

I have a custom page template that looks like this:

```
<?php if( is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
   <?php thinkup_input_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
   <?php thinkup_input_allowcomments(); ?>
   <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php else:
  wp_die('Sorry, you must first <a href="/wp-login.php">log in</a> to view this page. You can <a href="/wp-login.php?action=register">register free here</a>.');
endif; ?>
```

Now, when I browse to the page that uses this page template, I'm asked to login. After the login, I'm redirected to the Wordpress admin panel. Browsing manually to the page only shows the same login again.

- How can I ensure that is_user_logged_in() detects that I'm logged in; and
- That I'm redirected to the page itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SSL at all?

Comment: Yes, I have SSL activated for the admin section, as follows in the wp-config.php: define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

Comment: The following thread will explain why if you login via SSL, then any page where you check if user is logged in will also need to be secure https://wordpress.org/support/topic/http-and-https-differences-for-function-is_user_logged_in-in-wordpress-40#post-6079146

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing the ADMIN SSL login in `wp-config.php`, I solved this.

So, remove this:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Read more about this feature [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL)

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in with an account that's NOT an admin account. I think that's just a quirk of an admin account...it assumes you want to go to the control panel.

Comment: Nope, that is not it. I tried logging in with another ordinary user. I'm still redirected to the Dashboard (for that user) after logging in. Also, trying to navigate to the page after leads to the same login form again.